# I can't grab specific URL in search page

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, domparser, simpledom

I enter the estate website and searched by name of the city. After that I want to grab Osaka City building URL. In here `http://brillia.com/search/?area=27999`　**There are four of those.**

And I m using that link to grab URL.

```
$allDivs = $parser->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach ($allDivs as $div) {
        if ($div->getAttribute('class') == 'boxInfomation') {
            $allLinks = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach ($allLinks as $a) {
                $linkler[] = $a->getAttribute('href');
            }
        }
    }
```

But I cant grab those. Actually I grabbed not just osaka city pages URL actually grabbed all of it. When I try to see the source the osaka page site. It shows `http://brillia.com/search/` Thats why I m grabbing all other links...

But how can I grab just URLs in here -> `http://brillia.com/search/?area=27999`

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: do you want to grab only area=27999 ?

Comment: yes I want to grab only area=27999

Comment: you mean the value 27999 out of the url?

Comment: I mean, in area 27999 there are four building URL I want to grab those four URL, like comment below. gsmo83 did it with jquerry. But I want to do it with php domparser

Comment: In php as the attribute is a string, you should be able to match it with regexp. This would put it into $re if it is exact as you show. (It will not work if you have more word=number things though)


    `preg_match("/(?=\w+\=\d+).*/", $uri, $match);`


regex101 is a good place to try out these regular expressions, it also explains it a bit, which I am not super good at.

Also if I missudnerstand what you want this should be something to build from at least.

Comment: take a look at URLSearchParams.entries()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries
I don't know php much, so I don't know how mix js with your php code

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this by using jQuery? in that case this grab the a href

```
 $("div h3 a").each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(link);
 });
```

[here a jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/gsimo83/4s0ahkbv/11/)

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is I am using laravel with domparser, any other way to do this with that. my other bot working with php DOMparser.

Answer (score 1):

The parser relies on `libxml` to extract elements but that page is using html5 heavily, ommiting certain close tags, etc and that isn't really strict xml, so it's struggling to "correct mistakes" by guessing where to close missing tags, returning wrong results.

You need a parser with html5 support like `HTML5DOMDocument` that extends `DOMDocument` and should have mostly the same interface.

Comment: so you are saying I cant scrape that page with current DOMparser that I am using. I need to upgrade it or something or do I need to find another crawler?

Comment: Yes. You can't really upgrade `DOMDocument` since it's a php module but I suggested a library that *extends* it and *should* be compatible for the most part. You should only need to change the instantiation.