# I can't reach the table's td tag

Tags: php, laravel, domparser

I can't grab table's td tag. I'm trying to first td property and second for value. This is the website:

```
https://www.mecsumai.com/bkn-summary/?bid=16076001&bg1=026937&bg2=dce8e2&wdt=100%25&aln=center&newid=06076001
```

My foreach codes are hare:

```
$allTables = $DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('table');
        foreach ($allTables as $table) {
            foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {
                $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
                if ($tds->length == 2) {
                    $property = trim($tds->item(0)->nodeValue);
                    $value = trim($tds->item(1)->nodeValue);

                    switch ($property) {
                        case '販売価額':
                            $changeForMyDB['price'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '所在地':
                            $changeForMyDB['address'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '総戸数':
                            $changeForMyDB['hows_old'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '間取り':
                            $changeForMyDB['rooms'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '建物竣工':
                            $changeForMyDB['old'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '入居(予定)日':
                            $changeForMyDB['entery'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case 'バルコニー面積':
                            $changeForMyDB['balcon_m2'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '管理会社':
                            $changeForMyDB['company_name'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '物件名':
                            $changeForMyDB['name'] = $value;
                            break;
                        case '専有面積':
                            $changeForMyDB['extend'] = $value;
                            break;

                        default:
                            # code...
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Estates::insertGetId($changeForMyDB);
        $this->line('DATA saved.');
    }
}
}
```

I updated codes and getting no errors but still can't get the data.
What am I doing wrong here?
Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: There's no `th` element on that page, so you are never getting into the `switch`...

Comment: mate, any help to fix that problem? I changed th to td and gave those to number. But no change, @msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `DOMNodeList` directly as an array, but you have an equivalent method of accessing `Nodes`. I also added some lazy checks to make sure the `tr` has at least two elements corresponding to the property and value:

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile("https://www.mecsumai.com/bkn-summary/?bid=16076001&bg1=026937&bg2=dce8e2&wdt=100%25&aln=center&newid=06076001");

$allTables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach ($allTables as $table){
    foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
        $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
        if ($tds->length == 2) {
            $property = trim($tds->item(0)->nodeValue);
            $value = trim($tds->item(1)->nodeValue);
            $d[$property] = $value;
        }
    }
    if (isset($d)) {
        echo "Keys: " .  count($d) . "\n";
        unset ($d);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Keys: 31
Keys: 27
Keys: 30
```

Comment: I changed the table part, like you said but this time I am getting this error: `Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName()` updated question! you can check how I changed it.

Comment: At this part `foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {`

Comment: okay mate, I m not getting error now but still cant get the data, I updated the question codes. you can check it too. By the way thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I already checked it mate, and I received data saved massage on terminal but when I checked the database there is no data. you are saying foreach cycle is okay. Then problem is must be something else...

Comment: as I said, checked it no data :) I think foreach cycle is not working

Comment: if you have time, can you check this question? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659703/i-cant-grab-specific-url-in-search-page` this is so troublesome. Thank you, as always!